# python: call a function with parameter from input

Tags: python, function

I have a list of tuples consisting of name, phone number and address, and a function called "all" which just shows a list of all the tuples (like in a phonebook). The function is called via input from a user.

I want another function, called "entry" which shows a specific entry of my list. This function should be called via input as well with the index number of the entry (for example, "entry 12") and show just this entry.

Although I can't figure out how to take the number from the input as a parameter for my function and how to call the function. Does it have to contain a variable in the function name which will later be replaced by the number? How can i do that?

Comment: You could start by showing the piece of code that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into argparse?

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='your description')
parser.add_argument('-entry', dest="entry")
args = parser.parse_args()
print (args.entry)
```

You can then call this with `python yourfile.py -entry="this is the entry"`

That will allow you to take an input when you run the file.

Comment: looks like what i need! thanks, i'll check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if misunderstood your question, but it seems like you need function arguments. For example: if your `entry' program just prints out what the user put in, your code would look like this:

```
def entry(user_input): # the variable in the parentheses is your argument--is a local variable ONLY used in the function
    print user_input # prints the variable

# now to call the function--use a variable or input() as the function argument
entry(input("Please input the entry number\n >>> ") # see how the return from the input() function call is used as a variable? this basically uses what the user types in as a function argument.
```

Try running it, and you'll see how it works.

Best of luck and happy coding!